# Add sequence record numbers

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a table with with two fields: ID field (`FID`) as primary key and `Qty` both are integers. I need to query this table and add two additional fields as sequence serial using the QTY field so I can get results like this:

```
table1
-------------------------------------
ID   Qty   range_begin   range_end
50   2         1           2
53   1         3           3
65   3         4           6
67   2         7           8
```

`range_begin` field start at 1, next record should be `range_end + 1`.
And `range_end = last range_end + Qty`

I tried to write it using context variables Like this

I set all variables to null first

```
rdb$set_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'range_end', null);
rdb$set_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'range_begin', null);
```

Than I start the query:

```
Select 
  rdb$get_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'range_begin'),
  rdb$set_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'range_begin', COALESCE(CAST(rdb$get_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'range_end') AS INTEGER), 0) + 1)),

  rdb$get_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'range_end'),
  rdb$set_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'range_end', COALESCE(CAST(rdb$get_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'range_end') AS INTEGER), 0) + Qty)),

  Qty
  from table1 where ...
```

But I did not able to get the correct sequence. I also tried to add more variables and other things but none worked for me so how this should be done so I can use single select query ?

I am using FireBird 2.5 and it is not necessary for the answer to use context variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you want is

```
SELECT t.ID, t.QTY, 
  ((select coalesce(sum(qty),0) from table1 a where a.ID < t.ID) + 1) as RANGE_BEGIN,
  ((select coalesce(sum(qty),0) from table1 a where a.ID < t.ID) + t.qty) as RANGE_END
FROM table1 t
```

For a big table this might get slow, so instead of calculated field you might want to use permanent fields and calculate the range values in trigger... it depend how the data changes etc.

Comment: This table has more than 1M records but in this query the `where` clause return only 100 records so I am going to use your solution. thanks.

Comment: I want to ask please if the `ID` field is repeated I find `range_begin` does not start from 1 so is there a workaround this ?

Comment: Hmm, not off the top of my head right now... don't you have some PK in the table you could use instead of the `ID`?

Comment: The table is actually a view linked to many other tables each has its own PK. if there is no solution for this should I use selectable `For Select` inside a stored procedure ? I already wrote this procedure but I am getting some performance hit warnings from IBExpert.

Comment: Finally after several hours I did it using context variables and the sequence is correct.